# How to do performance monitoring in react-native mini apps?

Tags: typescript, firebase, react-native, performance, nx.dev

I have a react native mini app which is part of main app(react-native) created using [nx.dev](https://nx.dev/). Currently firebase has been added to main app which gives overall performance analytics of the app. I want to do performance monitoring(prod) specific to this mini app.

Is there a way (library, tools) to monitor the performance of mini-app in Production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how in depth you'd want your performance monitoring to be you have a few options here.
The easiest solution with react-native would be to plug your project with Firebase and monitor the performance of the app there. They have a few pre-defined metrics such as App Start & Screen renders which work quite well.
The more complex solution would be to utilise a library like **react-native-performance** along with flipper extension of this library to monitor metrics like FPS and record that live, when running the app in production. It really depends on your use case, here's a very good example on how to measure performance of production apps in react-native https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yl6gj0ZLB3Y
Hope this helps!

Comment: Problem is main app is already using it firebase for tracking performance so the dashboard gives overall performance analytics. I want to track performance specific to any mono-app.